# use jQuery to access dom after angularjs finished loading the view

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working on a project which I can't modify the angular scripts, however I was allowed to add my own jquery script, but the problem is angular still loading the view and because of that the element which I want to access with jquery doesn't exist yet, so how can I find out angular finished loading the view and then I can run my jquery script?

Comment: Once you have updated the model, you can examine the DOM after the current thread of execution returns and angular has `$apply()`'d any changes like so: `$timeout(function () {...your code...});` Note that you must inject `$timeout` into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('angular-app-name').run(function(){
    // angular should have loaded now, do your thing...
    $('#rocket').launch();
});
```

you could also try...

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    $('#harpies').release();
});
```

Comment: Note that this solution will only work on the initial page load and render. If you later modify the model, you will miss future changes to the DOM, unless you use my method above.

Comment: I have no clue about angular could you please explain what exactly I have to do? thanks

Comment: About above solutions: 

not working

angular.module('angular-app-name').run(function(){
    // angular should have loaded now, do your thing...
    $('#rocket').launch();
});

                                                                                                                                 
working, but still view is not loaded

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    $('#harpies').release();
});